# Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 fails

Tags: system-installation

When i try to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop alongside windows7, my notebook reboots and  starting to boot windows again. I tried several times but same thing here.

I have acer aspire 5750 notebook

Comment: When does the laptop reboot? Immediately after you press `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7`? Or later?

Comment: notebook rebooting when i select that option and click continue button..

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/343370/265974 and don't forget to **make a backup** before you change any partition. If you want to use hibernate, the swap size should be at least the ram size.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, you can make [a boot able USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), then go to BIOS and select boot from USB drive.

Comment: When i try to boot from usb, it stucks.. :(